# How do I disable red highlighting when there is an error in vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have looked at other questions and I can't quite find the exact question I'm looking for. Whenever I'm writing my code and I am halfway through, some red hightlightings appear in the file name which is quite distracting and I would like to get rid of.

Does anyone know how to do this?

In case I didn't explain myself very clearly, I am attaching a picture of what I mean.

[image]

Comment: If anyone also knows how to disable the red highlights when there is an error in the code I would appreciate it.

Comment: I mean, the red squiggly lines under each line when there's an error

Comment: there is a setting that enables the coloring of tabs based on errors and SCM status of a file, see some of the latest <62 release notes

Answer (score 0):

Press ctrl-shift-p, and type "Preferences: Open Settings (UI)", type "lint" in the search bar and on the left pane restrict your search to Python. From there, you'll likely see the extension that you're using that creates the red underline. On mine for example, I would set the "Python > Analysis > Type Checking Mode" to `off` to disable most red underlining, but your context may be more unique

Comment: I do have that option of "type checking mode" but it is already off

Comment: At the bottom of your vscode you may see a pane with some tabs, e.g. `Problems`, `Output`, etc. On windows you can pres (Windows+shift+`) to bring it up. In the problems tab, take a look at the warning itself and and what service is bringing it up. From there we can refine the search in your settings to resolve